# Elements of pandas not in an index list

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

How could I get the elements of a pandas DataFrame that are not in a given list of index?

A simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = np.linspace(10, 100, 10)

A = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=["A"])
ind = [x for x in range(1, 4)]
print(A.iloc[ind])
```

So for example, now I would like to get all the elements that are not in ind (so indexes 0,5,6,7,8,9)...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
print(A.iloc[A.index.difference(ind)])
       A
0   10.0
4   50.0
5   60.0
6   70.0
7   80.0
8   90.0
9  100.0
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `set`:

```
res = set(A.index) - set(ind)

{0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

This is syntactic sugar for `set(A.index).difference(set(ind))`.

As pointed out, this removes duplicates from `A.index` too.

Comment: This solution also removes duplicates